# Se sigue repite y repite el ciclo while

Tags: python, bucles, while

Buenas tardes estoy creando un programa sobre una batalla Pokémon con arte ASCII que incluí en una lista.

He estado viendo cual es mi error y no logro verlo, cuando ejecuto mi código se sigue repitiendo infinitas veces y no entiendo porque? se los agradecería muchísimo el hacerme ver mi error.
NOTA: Lo que se repite exactamente es el ataque de la pc

Aquí está mi código:

```
images = [pikachu, squirtle, bulbasur]
vida_usuario =int(80) 
vida_pc = int(80)

#elegir pokemon a base de una lista 
usuario_pokemon = int(input("Que pokemon tu eligues: [0] Pikachu, [1] Squirtle, [2] Bulbasur.\n"))
#print(images[usuario_pokemon])
#Codigo batalla
#pokemon de pc
pc = random.randint(0, 2)
print(f"Pc:{images[pc]}")
#ataque_pc = random.randint(1, 2)
#turno Pc
while vida_pc > 0 and vida_usuario > 0:
 ataque_pc = random.randint(1, 2)
 if ataque_pc == 1:
   vida_pc -= 11
   print("Te atacaron con Placaje!\n")
 else:
   vida_usuario -= 11
   print("Te atacaron con Araniazo!\n")
#turno Usuario
ataque_usuario = None
while ataque_usuario != "P" and ataque_usuario != "A":
 print('Tu turno:')
 print(images[usuario_pokemon])
 ataque_usuario = input("Que ataque quieres usar [A]araniazo, [P] placaje ?")
 
 if ataque_usuario == "A":
   print(f"Usas Araniazo!")
   vida_pc -= 10
   print(f"la vida de Pc es: {vida_pc}, Tu vida es {vida_usuario}\n")
 elif ataque_usuario == "P":
   print(f"Usas Placaje!")
   vida_pc -= 12
   print(f"la vida de Pc es: {vida_pc}, Tu vida es {vida_usuario}\n")
if vida_usuario > 0:
   print('Pc Gana !!!\n')
else:
 print('Gracias por Jugar!')
'''
```

Comment: Por favor, pon el código en un formato legible (texto) para facilitar su lectura, de esta manera puedes recibir ayuda más óptima. Recuerda que para algunos usuarios es muy difícil leer lo que pone una imagen y más si es código. Puedes leer más acerca de este tema en esta [discusión de StackOverflow Meta en Español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5047/es-adecuado-sugerir-el-cierre-de-preguntas-que-poseen-im%c3%a1genes-para-compartir-c/5050). Adicionalmente a esto, puedes leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](/help/how-to-ask). Saudos.

Comment: Puedes decir qué es lo que se repite infinitamente?

Comment: Desconozco Python, pero me parece que se repite el primer ciclo porque nunca se modifican las variables `vida_pc` y `vida_usuario`, todo porque el siguiente bloque de código es independiente, por no estar alineado (indentado) con el anterior.

Comment: Si no había pensando en eso, Muchas Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que he comprendido el problema.
La razón de que "en ocasiones" y no siempre, de ahí que costaba entenderlo, se ejecuta de forma "aleatoria" un número para realizar la decisión de quien ataca a quien.

Si te fijas en la primera parte donde asignas ataque_pc, es aleatorio, por lo que si sale 2 veces 1, atacará 2 veces al pc, entiendo.

Te traigo un par de propuestas generales. He creado una función que asigna "un daño aleatorio" y por otro lado, un contador "attack_count" con el que contabilizar cada ataque.

Entiendo que los turnos de ataque deben ser uno cada uno, primero pc y después opuesto. De esta froma utilizando los números pares e impares con el módulo (%), cada ataque se hará por turnos sin repetir, además del detalle de daño aleatorio. Con los "print" de debajo puede ver como se desarrolla el combate.

Espero que te ayude :)

```
images = [pikachu, squirtle, bulbasur]
vida_usuario =int(80) 
vida_pc = int(80)
#elegir pokemon a base de una lista 
usuario_pokemon = int(input("Que pokemon tu eligues: [0] Pikachu, [1] Squirtle, [2] Bulbasur.\n"))
#print(images[usuario_pokemon])
#Codigo batalla
#pokemon de pc
pc = random.randint(0, 2)
print(pc)
print(f"Pc:{images[pc]}")
#ataque_pc = random.randint(1, 2)
#turno Pc
def rand_dmg(hp):
    min_dmg = 1
    try: max_dmg = int(hp / 2)
    except: return 0

    try: return random.randint(min_dmg, max_dmg)
    except: return min_dmg

attacks_count = 0
while vida_pc > 0 and vida_usuario > 0:

    if attacks_count % 2:
        vida_pc -= rand_dmg(hp=vida_pc)
        print("Te atacaron con Placaje!\n")
    else:
        vida_usuario -= rand_dmg(hp=vida_usuario)
        print("Te atacaron con Araniazo!\n")

    attacks_count += 1
    print("vida_pc", vida_pc)
    print("vida_usuario", vida_usuario)


#turno Usuario
ataque_usuario = None
while ataque_usuario != "P" and ataque_usuario != "A":
    print('Tu turno:')
    print(images[usuario_pokemon])
    ataque_usuario = input("Que ataque quieres usar [A]araniazo, [P] placaje ?")

    if ataque_usuario == "A":
        print(f"Usas Araniazo!")
        vida_pc -= 10
        print(f"la vida de Pc es: {vida_pc}, Tu vida es {vida_usuario}\n")
    elif ataque_usuario == "P":
        print(f"Usas Placaje!")
        vida_pc -= 12
        print(f"la vida de Pc es: {vida_pc}, Tu vida es {vida_usuario}\n")

if vida_usuario > 0:
    print('Pc Gana !!!\n')
else:
    print('Gracias por Jugar!')
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Es verdad no había contemplado que es random y que eso pudo causar el ciclo infinito , no sabes como te lo agradezco :)